# Primary key auto increment as -1,-2,-3

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, primary-key

I'm Using Visual Studio 2010 and I created a Windows Form Application with a database connected to it.

There is a table in this database named "Students" and there is a field "StudentID" with attributs of

`PRIMARYKEY,NOTNULL,IDENTITY:TRUE, IDENTITY INCREMENT:1, IDENTITY SEED:1`.

I dragged one table to the application using data sources.

When I try to create new record using the database controllers in the application, StudentID automatically becomes -1.  If I hit new again it's -2.  It's increasing as negative values. I want it to increase as positive values.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: `When I try to create new record using the database controllers in the application, StudentID automatically become -1`.  It would be really helpful to post your actual code.

Comment: "please don't mark this question as not-useful" - the decision on whether to vote to close questions depends less on your level of experience, of pleas like the above, and more on whether you've put *effort* into your question, whether you appear to have researched it, etc.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - i'd do that but I'm using VS 2010 and I cant find the exact code for that operation :/

Answer (score 3):

> When I try to create new record using the database controllers in the application, StudentID automatically become -1 if i hit new again it's -2

By design. The negative values are temporary (in-memory only) values.

When you update to the actual Db and refresh they will have become positive numbers.

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but I've actually never observed that behavior before.  Do you know where this is documented?

Comment: Drag a table (with Identity PK) to a DataSet and link to a Grid on a WinForm. Then add some records. It's observable behaviour. Documented: long, long ago.